# Chrome devtools blank page when inspecting mobile app

Tags: android, google-chrome, ionic-framework, google-chrome-devtools

I am developing mobile app(in Ionic4), but I am not able to inspect it and debug it in chrome devtools. When I go to Chrome/inspect the device with running app appears in the list, but when I click on inspect, only blank page opens, it looks like this:

[device page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnTJY.png)
[blank inspect page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk16s.png)

When i hit Ctrl+Shift+I blank page reopens, and i can look into the console, there are some errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
at installExtraStyleRules (devtools_compatibility.js:1484)
at installBackwardsCompatibility (devtools_compatibility.js:1457)
at devtools_compatibility.js:1504
at devtools_compatibility.js:1506

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: keyIdentifier
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at installBackwardsCompatibility (devtools_compatibility.js:1381)
    at devtools_compatibility.js:1504
    at devtools_compatibility.js:1506

[Deprecation] Application Cache was previously restricted to secure origins only from M70 on but now secure origin use is deprecated and will be removed in M82.  Please shift your use case over to Service Workers.

Uncaught TypeError: Object.observe is not a function
at WebInspector.Main._createSettings (inspector.js:10380)
at WebInspector.Main._gotPreferences (inspector.js:10372)
at DevToolsAPIImpl.embedderMessageAck (devtools_compatibility.js:43)
at <anonymous>:1:13
```

Any ideas where is the problem? It happens only on this type of device, on other devices, it works great.

Answer (score 0):

I have a little experience with Ionic. Not a big fan, since this is the start of the bugs you will face. You have to be a professional expert Javascript programmer to understand every bit of the code Ionic uses to compile (to debug and find problems). And even then I find it hard to find some errors too.

My advice is to switch to React Native with the Typescript template. Since Typescript gives you the best linting, help with errors and compiling. I have built multiple apps using Ionic, all far less advanced and beautiful then my React Native work. As well as other programmers to understand you're code, it's better to use Typescript with generics, interfaces, classes and such... If you have any other questions, post them below and I edit this post.

Comment: I think this is not a problem of ionic, because the same app runs on all other devices with no problems and i can inspect it in devtools. Only on this one device i cant inspect it(beside it the app runs OK), its only that i cant connect to it via devtools. I think there is some problem in webview version but iam not sure.

i was thinking about react native for some time, but i would have to learn react. But so far i was working with angular and i like things like rxjs and typescript, so i dont know, if i would get used to react and react native. Its very different approach.